# NFS can be seen on network via direct input, but not discovered

Tags: networking, 20.04, nfs

Ubuntu 20.04 and my NFS shares are alive and well but I can not find them unless I type them in manually. This started once I installed samba, but if I disable samba, it does not allow them to be seen. I know all my shares so it isnt insane to type them all in but I want to know what I screwed up.

Here are my Exports - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XPXP4R8vHZ/

Here is my Fstab - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dtF4swf5y3/

What else can I provide? My mysql database is dead in the water as I cant access nfs in kodi or any app for that reason to select the files.

Comment: Update, fresh install of 20.04.2 and no dice, what am I missing, I really need some help!

Comment: 5 months and not one person can chime in?

Comment: Where are you trying to find them? Where are you typing them manually?

Comment: Windows to add as mapped drives, Kodi for sources. It is a Kodi server, and that's essentially it.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me where you're doing this manual finding.

Comment: If I manually type in the address //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/media/movies I can find my NFS share, but if I search for it on the network or any application that allows NFS shares to be searched for and found, Kodi for me, it does not display. An example would be if you turn off the ssid on your wifi, it is still there, bit not discoverable. My NFS "ssid" is off and I don't know why

Comment: Have you set your server to use NFSv4 protocol or NFSv3?

Comment: Where can I find that info?, I did nfsstat and it looks like v3 but I am not certain.

Comment: @muru Any other advise?